# How to get the size of the memory allocated dynamically?

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Allocating memory dynamically using malloc will return the address from where the memory is allocated. Before that address meta-data is stored; it's a struct.

```
struct malloc_chunk {  
    int      prev_size;
    int      size;           // size of memory allocated
    struct malloc_chunk* fd;
    struct malloc_chunk* bk;
    struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize;
    struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

I want to print value of size without using malloc_usable_size(). I tried but I am getting a segfault.  I am working on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: You know whats the size. You told it to `malloc()`.

Comment: "I tried",good but what?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @Havenard : yes i know the size but i want to fetch it from metadata.

Comment: What size do you want to know? The number you passed to `malloc`, the size that is used to allocate the memory chunk, or the size, that could be used without clobbering the heap?

Comment: i want to know what value is passed to malloc(). Is value passed to malloc & size used to allocate memory chunk different ?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: you can't. There is no need to save this value since `malloc` rounds it up to next chunk size.

Comment: Then what is the value of size member of struct malloc_chunk ? I am expecting it to be the value what we pass to malloc().

Comment: @Rafal, How do you find that `struct malloc_chunk` reference? It hasn't to be related to the pointer you get from **malloc(3)**.  Indeed, it can be completely unrelated.  Only **malloc(3)** knows that!!!

Comment: The most probable reason you get `SIGSEGV` is because you are not getting the right `struct malloc_chunk` reference.  You don't show the code that fails, so no more help can be issued.

Comment: @LuisColorado : code is very simple, i have allocated memory for a pointer & trying to print the value of size like this " printf("%d", *(ptr - 36)); ". I am using 64bit machine, see the struct above ( ptr - (size of four pointers + size of int)). If metadata is stored immediately before the address returned by malloc then i should get the value of size insted of SIGSEGV

Comment: @Rafal, it's not that simple.  If you substract 36 to ptr and ptr is a pointer to integer (as assumed from the pointer dereference and the value used at printf) you'll get an address far below the beginning of the structure.  You need to cast the pointer to `(struct malloc_chunk *)`, then substract `1`, and then dereference the pointer, as in `((struct malloc_chunk *)p - 1)->size`. That way you'll get a pointer to a `struct malloc_chunk` structure correctly positioned.

Answer (score 4):

The structure is implementation dependent. You should not use the information at all since it might change at the next compiler or even at the next compiler version.

You should manage the size of memory in user defined structures.

**Edit:**
Memory allocation algorithms usually work with some alignments to

- avoid unaligned addresses in further allocations
- provide best performance on architectures where unaligned access is allowed but could result in performance penalties
- reduce the heap fragmentation be using chunks that are a multiple of a base, e.g. 16 bytes.

Therefore `malloc` doesn't need to allocate exactly the size that you passed as parameter. It can allocate a chunk the is sufficient to hold the requested size but probably more. It's not necessary for `malloc`to store the original value, only the chunk size is necessary to `free` the chunk.

Therefore it's probably impossible to retrieve the size parameter passed in the `malloc` function call.

Comment: Yes that is true structure is implementation dependent and it may or may not change in the next version. But as of now if i am not wrong the struct used is the one i mention above, so can we print it from there ??

Comment: It isn't so much the compiler as the library — `malloc()` et al are library functions, not directly implemented by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, the exact mechanism `malloc` uses to store the size -- if it even has a mechanism -- is going to be implementation defined. You need to keep track of the size yourself if you need it for anything specific.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following test code (which has no error checking):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *v1 = malloc(160);
    void *v2 = malloc(160);
    void *v3 = malloc(160);

    printf("v1 = %p\n", v1);
    printf("v2 = %p\n", v2);
    printf("v3 = %p\n", v3);

    ptrdiff_t d1 = v2 - v1;
    ptrdiff_t d2 = v3 - v2;

    printf("d1 = %td\n", d1);
    printf("d2 = %td\n", d2);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the output I got was:

```
v1 = 0x742010
v2 = 0x7420c0
v3 = 0x742170
d1 = 176
d2 = 176
```

Since the gap between the returned blocks is 176 bytes and the size allocated is 160 bytes, there are just 16 bytes of overhead.  The `struct malloc_chunk` outlined in the question occupies 40 bytes on a 64-bit platform (24 on a 32-bit platform).  It does not fit into the space between allocated chunks of memory.

Therefore, any attempt to access a `struct malloc_chunk` from a regular block of allocated memory is doomed to failure.

You will have to obtain the source to `malloc()` to find out how it uses that structure.  If I had to guess, it uses it in a separate area altogether.  Maybe some of the 16 bytes of overhead tells `malloc()` where to find the `struct malloc_chunk`.  But that's a guess; I've not looked.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `malloc_usable_size` is Linux/Unix specific function and will not work on Windows, for example.

So, the best way is to save size when allocating memory: just remember how much memory was allocated and than use that value.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using ubuntu 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc library normally maintains a list of `struct malloc_chunk` internally to manage the amounts of memory given to the user up to this point.  Normally, to cope with that they have a way to map the returned pointer from **malloc(3)** to the address of this structure (so **free(3)** can get to it), but you don't know that mapping for sure.

Normally, they alloc internally the amount to store the memory they give to you and this `struct malloc_chunk` together, and the struct is aligned in a way that they can get the structure address from the pointer you pass to `free(3)`.

The normal way to cope with this is: The **malloc(3)** function gives you `(void *)(ref + 1)`, where `ref` is a `struct malloc_chunk *` pointer (so it's aligned to the end of this structure) and you have to do just the opposite to get a valid pointer to that structure, that is: `((struct malloc_chunk *)ptr - 1)` (convert the pointer to a `struct malloc_chunk *` pointer, and then go back one structure size to point there)

This expression is of type pointer to `struct malloc_chunk`, so you can reference its fields with the following code:

```
void *p = malloc(120);
struct malloc_chunk *mc = (struct malloc_chunk *)p - 1;

printf("prev_size:   %d\n"
       "size:        %d\n"
       "fb:          %p\n"
       "bk:          %p\n"
       "fw_nextsize: %p\n"
       "bk_nextsize: %p\n",
       mc->prev_size,
       mc->size,
       mc->fb,
       mc->bk,
       mc->fw_nextsize,
       mc->bk_nextsize);
```

I have not been able to test this code, as my `<malloc.h>` implementation doesn't have this `struct malloc_chunk` type defined anywhere (or I have not been able to find it).  You have to provide a reference of where do you have acquired this type if you want me to be able to reproduce your environment.  I'm using `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`

Comment: i am using library glibc-2.20, in this malloc/malloc.c i found the struct malloc_chunk

Comment: @Rafal, and how are you going to get that structure in your source file?  Do you think including the whole file `malloc.c` ??? Being in `malloc/malloc.c` means it's a private structure.  It chan change even between minor version updates of the malloc library, as it's not exported anywhere.  It's for private use of malloc and the author reserves the right of changing it whenever s/he wants.  What do we do next?  Off course, if you have the source of **malloc(3)** you can get at how malloc converts from internal pointer to external and do the opposite.

Comment: yes i am already analyzing how malloc is implemented, Thanks for your support. Do you know any link where i can get documentation of malloc ?

Comment: There are several algorithms for memory allocation due to Aho et al.  But don't have here the references.  Sorry.  Google with Aho and malloc.  Perhaps you'll find something.